# aws dynamodb pricing - is my bill already counting in free tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Provisioned Mode and I am under DynamoDB free tier.

From Dynamodb Dashboard
There are 6 tables with 10 RCU and WCU each.

```
Total capacity
Provisioned read capacity   60 (Max: 80000)
Provisioned write capacity  60 (Max: 80000)
```

> DynamoDB free tier
> The AWS Free Tier enables you to gain free, hands-on experience with AWS services. The following DynamoDB benefits are included as part of the AWS Free Tier. Each benefit is calculated monthly on a per-region, per-payer account basis.
> 25 WCUs and 25 RCUs of provisioned capacity
> 25 GB of data storage
> 25 rWCUs for global tables deployed in two AWS Regions
> 2.5 million stream read requests from DynamoDB Streams
> 1 GB of data transfer out (15 GB for your first 12 months), aggregated across AWS services

Since my current provisioned read and write capacity is already exceeding 25 units,
I'm just wondering if the dynamodb service become not free in this situation?

If so, how should my bill be counted in this month, how much would I be charged for in this month?

Answer (score 1):

From [FAQ for Free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/free-tier-faqs/):

> If your application use exceeds the free tier limits, you simply **pay standard, pay-as-you-go service rates** (see each service page for full pricing details). Restrictions apply; see offer terms for more details.

Since you are using 60 RCUs and WCUs, you will have to pay for **45 units each**. 25 RCUs and WCUs will fall within the free tier.

[DynamoDB pricing examples](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/) provided by AWS provide scenarios which show how to calculate DdB price when you exceed the limits. In short, whatever you have to pay for 60 units, free tier will reduce by 25 units:

> The AWS Free Tier includes 25 WCUs and 25 RCUs, reducing your monthly bill by $14.04